# CSS Background image not showing with height auto

Tags: height

I have a div with a background image in it. I have to specify a height in px for it to show. But I want it to show with height auto as the width resizes. I am stuck. 
When I have height auto it just does not show the image at all...

```
#slider-shadow1 {
z-index: 9999;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background: url(images/layouts/shadow2.png)  center no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
position:relative;
display: inline-block;
background-size:cover;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Height: auto` means the height of element is exactly the same as elements content. If you have empty element, its height is zero. And you can't see background image (you see exactly 0px of them).